# About DDR3 and DDR5 on a specific laptop

Tags: ram

I just bought myself a new laptop(check link for details) and i was wondering how could i know if my laptop is compatible with running DDR5 ram, instead of DDR3. I have 2 slots and i really want to upgrade to DDR5. I have been searching on google for motherboard specs, but i am a little new to this stuff. So, can anyone please tell me if my laptop can run DDR5? Thanks a lot.

http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NX.MP4AA.007

Answer (score 1):

There is no DDR5 available, maybe you are confusing with GDDR5 which is embedded on a discrete graphic card ?

The listed laptop is compatible with DDR3L (low voltage)

Comment: Oh, i see. Thank you very much. I guess the only thing i can do to improve the laptop is to get a SSD mSATA. Have a nice day.